# What does そうじゃなくて mean in this context?

Tags: translation, meaning

**現在はごちゃごちゃしていてあんまりいいこともなくて、と思っていると、そういうふうになるので、そうじゃなくて**、追憶というのは未來に対してすべきなんじゃないでしょうか。

May I know what does the bolded sentence mean?
Does it mean that  **If I think that I am messed up and there are no good things at present, the situation will become so?** 
But I have no clue about the そうじゃなくて that comes after. そういうふうになる means it will become but そうじゃなくて means it is not like that. It seems the two are contradictory to each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess "そうじゃなくて" here in the sentence negates the way of thinking "現在はごちゃごちゃしていてあんまりいいこともなくて" as you described "If you think like things have been messing up and not really that good things happen, things tend to be so." And she gives advice "You shouldn't think like that. Recalling should be projected onto the future." I think "追憶" is a hint for what they are actually talking about.